# How to calculate the super-triangular surround the set of points in Bowyer-Watson algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, triangulation

First, sorry for my bad English. Follow my question, in Bowyer-Watson algorithm, we must find a super-triangular surround all points. But how can we calculate the coordinator (x,y) of 3 verticles of that super-triangular ? Anyone have a fomular for this ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Is this a programming question? It sounds more mathematical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proof for this but what first comes to mind is doing something with getting the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)  of your set of points

```
1. Get the convex hull of the group of points.
2. Initialize the variable smallest = infinity.
3. For each point P in convex hull do the following:
       Find the point farthest away from P call it Q.
       Set N1 = point to the left of P (counter-clockwise along convex hull).  
           N2 = point to the right of P (clockwise along convex hull).
           L1 = line that intersects Q and is perpendicular to the line PQ.
           L2 = line that intersects P and N1.
           L3 = line that intersects P and N2.
           A = area of the triangle thats formed by the intersections of L1,L2,L3.
       If A < smallest, then set smallest = A.
4. Return smallest
```

This, of course, returns a number which isn't too helpful so instead you could just do something like create a triangle class

```java
class Triangle{
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    Point p3;
    double Area;
    //etc...
}
```

and change `smallest` to like `triangle.area` or something so that you end up keeping track of the points.